# How to use sp_helptext in Linqpad

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I'm trying the 'LinqPad Challenge' but I've come up with a usage scenario that has stumped me.

For a given database, I am able to successfully query the 'sp_helptext' sproc using SQL as the language

```
-- SQL
sp_helptext '[mySchema].[usp_myProc]'
```

however the sp_helptext sproc does not seem to have generated a corresponding method in my Linq2Sql context, and as such I can't query this function using C#.

```
// C#
sp_helptext("[mySchema].[usp_myProc]")
```

is there some other way to access the sp_helptext function using C# as the language for my query.

Comment: i think system procedures are not being part of C# environment in linqpad...

Comment: @vishalsharma I thought that too, but I can see that some of the system procedures are included.  At least those related to 'diagrams' anyway (i.e. sp_alterdiagram, sp_creatediagram, sp_dropdiagram, etc).  You may still be right and this is just a selective include though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click your connection, choose **Properties** and check **Include System Views and SPs**. You'll then notice a **sys** database in the schema, containing the system views and SPs, and the following will work:

```
sys.sp_helptext ("mySchema.usp_myProc")
```